# copy_n or until eof?

Tags: c++, algorithm, file

How would I do this using STL algorithms?

```
std::ifstream file(filename);

std::vector<unsigned char> buf;
for(auto file_it = std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file); file_it != std::istreambuf_iterator<char>() && buf.size() < 2048; ++file_it)
    buf.push_back(*file_it);
```

Note `buf.size() < 2048`.

e.g. what will happen if I do the following, and the file is smaller than 2048 bytes?

```
std::copy_n(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), 2048, std::back_inserter(buf));
```

Comment: What happens if the file is larger? Is the rest of it discarded or do you need an iterator to the begin of the part that is still left to be read?

Comment: The ifstream is discarded once the required number of bytes have been read.

Comment: This opens up the possibility to have a separate iterator instead of an algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the documentation says,  `std::copy_n()` will copy *exactly* `n` items.  It will keep reading past the end of the sequence the iterator refers to.  I'm not sure what the standard says about `istreambuf_iterator<>`, though.  It's probably undefined behavior, but streams are likely to produce lots of copies of `eof()` past the end.  This might lead to lots of garbage when there are less than `2048` bytes available.

In any case, if you want to reliably copy *up to* `n` items, you'll need to write your own function:

```
template<typename I1, typename I2, typename size_type>
I copy_upto_n ( I1 begin, I1 end, size_type n, I2 out )
{
    for (size_type i=0; (i < n) && (begin != end); ++i)
    {
        *out++ = *begin++;
    }
    return out;
}
```

Some people might use `std::iterator_traits<>` instead of an extra template parameter to force the same distance type as the iterator.

Comment: +1 For the generic iterator algorithm and the mentioning of `std::iterator_traits`.

Comment: `out` should probably be a separate template argument.

Comment: @pmr: Indeed.  Without that, it won't work for the use case posted in the question (e.g. using `std::back_inserter()`).  I'll edit the code.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Now that I think of it though, using iterator traits is not necessary.  Just like `std::copy_n()`, there should be an additional template parameter for the integer type.  Then, `i` can represent all vallues in `[0,n)`.

Comment: @AndréCaron Yes, even better, as it isn't really used as an iterator distance, but an independent counter.

Comment: Does boost have anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a special `back_insert_iterator` that discards operations based on a predicate.

This code has been shamelessly taken from the GCC implementation of
the stdlib and adapted. A C++03 version should only require a
`Container::const_reference` in the assignment.

```
template<typename Container, typename Predicate>
class discarding_back_inserter
  : public iterator<output_iterator_tag, void, void, void, void>
{
  Container* container;
  Predicate p;
public:
  typedef Container          container_type;

  explicit
  back_insert_iterator(Container& x, Predicate p) : container(&__x), p(p) { }

  back_insert_iterator&
  operator=(const typename Container::value_type& value)
    {
      if(*container) 
        container->push_back(__value);
      return *this;
    }

  back_insert_iterator&
  operator=(typename _Container::value_type&& value)
    {
      if(*container) 
        container->push_back(std::move(__value));
      return *this;
    }

  back_insert_iterator&
  operator*()
    { return *this; }

  back_insert_iterator&
  operator++()
    { return *this; }

  back_insert_iterator
  operator++(int)
    { return *this; }
};
```

Comment: Don't take this personally, but, eww.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Nah, never. I just though it worth to look for the opposite approach to modifying the algorithm. The result isn't even very general purpose as it works on the container. I would really like to have a version of `generate` based on a `Maybe` value. That would make this really easy.

Comment: This does not use the predicate at all. It might work if the predicate stored a pointer to the stream, so that it can check for eof. The value argument won't give much info.

Comment: @UncleBens Ah, right. I forgot it should be  `if(p(*container))`.